# Sitecore 6.4: Can I add a ASP.NET HtmlGenericControl to an Items Sublayout programmatically?

Tags: asp.net, sitecore

I'm updating an item programmatically. I have a method which returns a HtmlGenericControl. I want to place this HtmlGenericControl into a (placeholder inside a) sublayout of the the item programmatically.
Is that possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "place this htmlControl programmaticaly"? A Sublayouts always has UserControl(.ascx) associated to it, where you can do whatever you need.

Comment: yes, but my code is not in the codebehind of the .ascx. I'm creating an item from an external source and like to put some html inside its sublayout

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean this:

```
// This is where your method returns the control.
HtmlGenericControl htmlControl = GetControl(); 

// This is how you add it as a child control of a placeholder
myPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(htmlControl);
```

Comment: thanks, but i need to access the placeholder via the Sitecore item. Something like item.presentation.sublayout.controls.add(htmlControl)

Comment: Let me get this straight: you are rendering an item and need to access one of its sublayouts to add a control to it? Are you trying to do that from the Layout or from another Sublayout? Just to be clear, there is no such thing as a sublayout control in an item, it only exists as part of a layout you are using to render an item.